# .Net Desktop Application

Tags: c#

I am using C# to develop my Desktop Application.
Now I had a requirement to have a IMAGE on button like we have at desktop or any form.
I want to know that is there any way to have an image on Button.

I want to know if it is possible.

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF? C# is a little vague.

Comment: There's no such thing as "C#.NET"

Comment: I was considering editing the post as an actual question but it's a little confusing.  Reading this, it sounds like you really want to add pictures and have them work like Windows desktop icons.  Also you don't mention what technologies you are using here.  Please let us know if you are using **WPF** or **Windows Forms** and try to rephrase what you want to do exactly so it is clear for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of desktop application, Windows Forms or WPF? In WPF it's simple:

```
<Button>
  <Image Source="img.png" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms add the `Button` to the `Form` and look in the Properties panel (press F4 if you don't see it) for the `Image` property.